# How to implement z-order sort for coordinates for Quad-Tree bulk insertion - C++

Tags: c++, bulkinsert, z-order, quadtree

According to [Improved Bulk-Loading Algorithms for Quadtrees](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~hjs/pubs/acmgis99.pdf), sorting the coordinates in z-order before insert will result in speedup for QuadTree batch insertion.

I need z-order implementation in C++. 
I have x,y coordinates both `double`. The solution here in Wikipedia for [Z-Order-Curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve)
is kind of unclear to me.

**EDIT - assumptions**
The coordinates I have are in google coordinates and are floating point numbers. 
In the system we currently develop, we assume that any bulk (batch) to be inserted fits in RAM. We don't anticipate the need of external sort operations with swapping between disk and memory.

**EDIT 2** 
with regards to the fact that Z-order works for integers only, I think the trick is to multiple by factors of 10 until all data is integers. Once I have that what is the way to perform z-order on the points?

Comment: As far as I know, Z-order isn't defined (or definable) on fractional coordinates

Comment: @harold, the diagonal argument would suggest otherwise.

Comment: @harold see edit. A simple trick of scaling the points will get rid of fractions.

Comment: @Saher, you can reinterpret cast to a uint64_t and Z-order on that.  However, that's either unspecified behavior or implementation defined behavior.

Comment: ok sounds good but how do I do the z-order, I am not sure it is clearly described the algorithm which I should use to perform the order. Thanks

Comment: @Saher, I'll write something up on that with a version of the reinterpret cast that avoids UB (I think...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested code, you should double check if it works.

Also, this code is almost certainly not portable, and might even be undefined behavior.  It's certainly implementation defined behavior at the very least, but it's probably unspecified... I'd have to more carefully read the rules regarding `reinterpret_cast` to and from `char*` to know for sure.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

uint64_t reinterpretDoubleAsUInt(double d) {
  int const doubleSize = sizeof(double);
  char* array = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&d);
  uint64_t result = 0;
  for (auto i = 0; i < doubleSize; ++i) {
    result += (uint64_t)array[i] << (8*i);
  }

  return result;
}

bool lessThanZOrderDouble(std::vector<double> const& a, std::vector<double> const& b) {
  uint64_t j = 0;
  uint64_t x = 0;
  if (a.size() != b.size() || a.size() == 0) {
    throw std::exception();
  }

  int dimensions = a.size();

  for (auto i = 0; i < dimensions; ++i) {
    auto y = reinterpretDoubleAsUInt(a[i]) ^ reinterpretDoubleAsUInt(b[i]);
    if (x < y && x < (x ^ y)) {
      j = i;
      x = y;
    }
  }
  return (a[j] - b[j]) > 0;
}

int main() {
  // blank for compilation's sake
}
```

Comment: I'm confused with regards to the lessThanZOrderDouble function? this takes in all the x and y coordinates, right as vector<double> `a` and `b`? If so, how does that perform a sort when it returns a single boolean for the whole list?

Comment: It's a less-than function that you can pass to a stl sorting function.

Comment: Oh ok so it is the comparison function? But I thought comparison functions take two values not the whole lists as arguments? right?

Comment: For greater clarity I should have used a `std::pair<double, double>` for the arguments, because you're only dealing in 2 dimensions.  The lists passed to the comparison function are your coordinates.  You're sorting a list of list of doubles, so your comparison function should take a list of doubles.